# How to make a unit move and not stop to attack in company of heroes

Tags: company-of-heroes

This is driving me crazy,

If I order any unit to move, specially to retreat from danger I find seconds after that they stop to shoot and attack anything hey see on their way.

Just imagine I order a cromwell command tank to retreat and he stops to use his MG on double bazooka granadiers..

Of course I mean for them to move, not to retreat to base

Is there any way to order the units to move and not stop?

Comment: To move, right click on the ground somewhere with the unit you want to move selected, and they will go there regardless of enemies.

Answer (score 1):

To move without stopping to attack, simply select the unit you want to move and right click the location you want to move it to. You can't do this with any of the buttons in the lower right corner, because there is no move button. Right click to move is so ubiquitous in RTS games that Relic presumably assumed nobody would ever use such a UI element, as it would be completely superfluous.

Comment: I do that but the units stop to attack enemies. Tanks even turn around  :S

Comment: they'll attack while moving but they will not stop. Whatever you are experiencing is not the standard behavior otherwise.

Comment: hmm ok will try next time +1